# I can not create a foreign key MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have problem with FK. (Sorry for my Eng)
I have a parent table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Специальность` (
`Код специальности` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`Название специальности` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`Код специальности`)
);
```

Then I want to create a child table referring to the parent

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Специальность \ Группа` (
`Номер группы студента` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`Код специальности` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`Курс группы` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`Номер группы студента`,`Код специальности`),
FOREIGN KEY(`Код специальности`) REFERENCES `специльность` (`Код специальности`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I get the Error **#1005 - Can't create table 'сессия.специальность \ группа'**

I started looking for what this error means.And I realized that the problem is not in the type of tables, because they are InnoDB. And also that the types and sizes of table attributes are the same.
I also tried to do so

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Специальность \ Группа` (
`Номер группы студента` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`Код специальности` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`Курс группы` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`Номер группы студента`,`Код специальности`),
KEY `Код специальности` (`Код специальности`),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(`Код специальности`) REFERENCES `специльность` (`Код специальности`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Forgive for the Russian words, but I hope you understand that it's not in them

Comment: Voting to close question as it was due to a simple typographical error in the table name.

Comment: Hi. This isa faq, google the error message without your application-specific words & look at all the possibilities. Also read every mention of FK in the official manual.